# LyX Editing error: Math text appears as blank rectangles while editing

Tags: errors, lyx

I have got this weird error that after inserting math and exiting the math box, the whole text appears as below:

[image]

The problem is while writing my text, I don't see the previous math equation. I am using LyX on a mac OS.

Comment: What program is that?

Comment: edited the description , thanks

Comment: Try to disable `Instant Preview` at `Tools->Preferences->Look & Feel->Display`